# TypeScript Error: "Type '{ todo: TodoInterFace; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TodoInterFace'How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I am doing a small home project to improve my skills in TS. Giving data to an array, everything is good, todos started to be displayed without errors.
TodoDisplay.tsx`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { todoContext } from '../pages/_app'
import styles from "../styles/TodosDisplay.module.css"
import { TodoInterFace } from '../interfaces/TodoInterface'
import Todo from './Todo'
function TodoDisplay() {

    
  const {todos} = useContext(todoContext)
  return (
    <div className={styles.todoDisplay}>

         {todos&& todos.map((todo)=>{
          return <Todo todo={todo}/>  
         })}

    </div>
  )
}

export default TodoDisplay
```

`Todo.tsx`

```
import { TodoInterFace } from "../interfaces/TodoInterface"
import styles from "../styles/Todo.module.css"

function Todo(todo:TodoInterFace) { 
  return (
    <div className={styles.todo}>
          <p >asdasdasd</p>
        <p >20/12/2000</p>
        
        
        <div className={styles.butttons}>
            <button>Delete</button>
            <button>Complete</button>
        </div>    
    </div>
  )
}

export default Todo
```

`

Then I decided to put the code with the map in a separate component and use useContext hook and than td immediately gave me an error:

Comment: Show your context

Comment: Sharing the code of the interface and the context would be helpful

Comment: here is the interface: export type TodoInterFace ={
    name:string,
    description:string,
    date:string,
    isDone:Boolean,
    id:string
}

Comment: `function Todo({todo}:TodoInterFace) { `